# Is explicit flush necessary for interleaved cout and cin operations?

Tags: c++, stream, iostream, flush

I notice that in many source code files one can see that writing to `cout` just before reading from `cin` *without* an  explicit flush:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin; using std::cout;

int main() {
    int a, b;
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Another nomber: ";
    cin >> b;
}
```

When this executes and the user inputs `42[Enter]73[Enter]` it nicely prints (g++ 4.6, Ubuntu):

```
Please enter a number: 42
Another number: 73
```

Is this defined behavior, i.e. does the standard say that somehow **`cout` is flushed before `cin` is read**? Can I expect this behavior on all conforming systems?

Or should one put an **explicit `cout << flush`** after those messages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The stream `std::cout` is tied to `std::cin` by default: the stream pointed to by `stream.tie()` is flushed prior to every properly implement input operation. Unless you changed the stream tied to `std::cin`, there is no need to flush `std::cout` before using `std::cin` as it will be done implicitly.

The actual logic to flush the stream happens when constructing a `std::istream::sentry` with an input stream: when the input stream isn't in failure state, the stream pointed to by `stream.tie()` is flushed. Of course, this assumes that the input operators look something like this:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, T& value) {
    std::istream::sentry cerberos(in);
    if (sentry) {
        // read the value
    }
    return in;
}
```

The standard stream operations are implemented this way. When user's input operations are not implemented in this style and do their input directly using the stream buffer, the flush won't happen. The error is, of course, in the input operators.